# HTML & CSS: Can't center my tables

Tags: html, css, html-table, centering

I'm struggling to get my 3 tables to be centered in the page.

Here's a picture of what it looks like currently:

[image: http://s2.postimg.org/5qbkb264p/tables.png]

Basically (from look at the image), I want the second/middle table ("Work" table) to be the only table in center, and the other 2 tables ("About" and "Collaborate" tables; left and right from the middle, respectively) to have spread out a bit (using margin, I would assume).

Here's my HTML:

```css
.fixedWidth2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}

.tableProp1 {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: ;
}

.tableProp1 tr td {
  height: 200px;
  color: red;
}

.tableProp2 {
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.tableProp2 tr td {
  height: 200px;
  color: pink;
}

.tableProp3 {
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.tableProp3 tr td {
  height: 200px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainContent">
  <div class="fixedWidth2">
    <table class="tableProp1" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>About</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Learn more about me and my accomplishments.</td>
    </table>
    <table class="tableProp2" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Work</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>I tend to get involved with a lot of different projects. Ranging from a simple photoshop gig to having a small role in a television/pilot</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="tableProp3" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Collaborate</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Have a brand new or idea of a project? Whatever help you may need, I may be of some assistance to</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- Fixed Width 2 DIV for Main Content DIV -->
</div>
<!-- mainContent DIV -->
```

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't use a `<table>` for this purpose. Using three [`<section>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section) seems to be a good choice. The headings "About", "Work" and "Collaborate" would each be `<h1>` elements as they are a heading for their section. [Rokos answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26209082/2930477) is on the money.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using fixed widths for your tables and you're floating them, I would wrap them in a container, set the width on that to match all three tables+margin and set `margin: auto` on the container

```
.table-wrapper{
  width: 680px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wLub0wrz/)

Alternatively you can just use `display: inline-block` instead of `float:left` and add `text-align: center` to `.fixedWidth2`

[ALT FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yjq8ymgv/)

Comment: THANKS, JMORE009! I tried out the first method, and works beautifully. I guess I missed that fixedWidth2 was the div itself, and couldn't manipulate the tables within it. Good call on making a table wrapper class!

Comment: @user3385997 there should be a check mark under the up/down vote count

Answer (score 1):

I would not use `<table>` at all... table are good for tabular content, not for templating....
I would use `DIV` or even HTML5's `<article>` and `<section>`.
Think also about SEO, `<h2>` is a better mirror to your website semantic toward search engines than table's `TH` ...

To center three elements you can simply set them `display: inline-block;` with some `vertical-align`, than just setting the `<div class="centered">` to `text-align: center;` will center-align your inner elements. You can also use `float:left;` but I've not covered that example.

http://jsbin.com/roruqo/1/

```
<div id="container">

  <div id="slider"></div>

  <div id="mainContent">

    <div class="centered">
      <div class="fixedWidth2">
        <h2>About</h2>
        <p>Learn more about me and my accomplishm...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="fixedWidth2">
        <h2>Work</h2>
        <p>I tend to get involved with a lot of d...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="fixedWidth2">
        <h2>Collaborate</h2>
        <p>Have a brand new or idea of a project?...</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div><!-- mainContent DIV -->


</div>
```

```
h2, p{
  padding:15px;
  margin:0;
}

#container{
  width:960px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:#eee;
}
#slider{
  background:blue;
  height:400px;
}
.centered{
  text-align:center;
}
.centered > div{
  text-align:left;
}
.fixedWidth2{
  min-height:170px;
  background:#ddd;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 15px;
}
.fixedWidth2 h2{
  text-align:center;
  background:#aaa;
}
```

Comment: @misterManSam thanks for *Die Antwoord* (or it's *Vanilla Ice*?) :)

Comment: [Vanilla Ice of course!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rog8ou-ZepE) Those lyrics have ruined the word "collaborate" for me; first thing I think of when I hear that word.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div id="mainContent">
          <div class="fixedWidth2">
            <div class="row">
            <table class="tableProp1" border="1">
              <tr>
                <th>About</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Learn more about me and my accomplishments.</td>
            </table>
            <table class="tableProp2" border="1">
              <tr>
                <th>Work</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>I tend to get involved with a lot of different projects. Ranging from a simple photoshop gig to having a small role in a television/pilot</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="tableProp3" border="1">
              <tr>
                <th>Collaborate</th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Have a brand new or idea of a project? Whatever help you may need, I may be of some assistance to</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
          </div>

        </div>


    add this style in style sheet

    .row {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 680px;
    }


add  "row " division and apply this style then check  it's working properly.
```